New horror movie about a possessed woman excorcised with an electric pulse machine
I recently was searching for some latest horror movies on YouTube when I came across this trailer where a couple was sitting back to back in their living room. 
The man was watching TV while the woman was using her cell phone when she suddenly gets possessed. Her back arches back and she kills the man. 
Then it showed a black girl entering the room with a big gun with some electric pulse. 
The girl shot the woman and took her somewhere in a big dome-like hall where her people used some electric pulse machine and took out the ghost from the woman in the form of an electric pulse and transferred it to some large liquid pool. 
Then that electric pulse comes out in its huge real form.
I forgot the name of the movie and since then I've been searching this trailer on YouTube but not getting it.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give?Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Check your YouTube history. The video should be in there. (If you're using a browser on a computer, instead of a phone, "History" is in the column on the left.)

I tried it on tubemate and it is not showing any history

You could also try searching your browsing history, depending on your browser where to look.

TL;DR; The Conjuring - 1
